# Как сменить размер изображения в зависимости от ориентации устройства

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На jquery нужно подгонят картинку под размер экрана при повороте устройства. Не могу сообразить где не так в коде. 
За помощь буду благодарен и вам +1 к карме)))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Foto preview v_2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
        img {display: block;position: absolute;left: 50%;top:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="gallery/1-1.jpg" alt="">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var $win_width = $(window).width(),
                $win_height = $(window).height(),
                $img_preview = $("img"),
                $img_width = $img_preview.width(),
                $img_height = $img_preview.height();

            //elementFullHeight($img_preview);

            /*if ($img_height >= $win_height) {

                elementFullWidth($img_preview);

            } else {elementFullHeight($img_preview);}*/

            function changeImgSize() {

                if ($win_width < $win_height) {

                    if ($img_width >= $win_width) {

                        elementFullWidth($img_preview);

                    } else {

                        elementFullHeight($img_preview);

                    }


                } else if ($win_width > $win_height) {

                    if ($img_width >= $win_width) {

                        elementFullWidth($img_preview);

                    } else {

                        elementFullHeight($img_preview);

                    }

                }


            }

            function visibleElement(element) {element.css({"opacity":"1"});}
            function invisibleElement(element) {element.css({"opacity":"0"});}
            function elementFullHeight(element) {element.css({"width":"auto","height":"100" + "%"});}
            function elementFullWidth(element) {element.css({"width":"100" + "%","height":"auto"});}
            function elementAutoSize(element) {element.css({"width":"auto","height":"auto"});}

            $(window).on("orientationchange resize", changeImgSize);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что не так-то?

Answer (score 2):

Вы уверены, что требуется писать для этого скрипт?
Попробуйте использовать css media queries.

```
@media(orientation: portrait)
@media(orientation: landscape)
```

Например:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)
{
  img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Enquire.js](http://loftblog.ru/material/sozdayom-prodvinutye-adaptivnye-sajty-vmeste-s-enquire-js/) — это ‘легкая’, независящая от каких-либо фреймворков, javascript библиотека для работы с CSS media queries.

Очень удобно использовать вместе с ajax и подгружать именно тот контент который необходим.

Работать с ней очень просто:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 45em"), {
match : function() {
    // подгружаем контент аяксом
},  
unmatch : function() {
    // если не соответствует условию
}
```

});

Comment: Коллеги, тут суть в том, что на странице есть любые картинки по контенту. Я кликаю на любую картинку (размеры то же любые), и она открывается в модальном окне, при этом растягивается на всю ширину или высоту. Вот как растянуть я и не могу сделать. Вернее сделал, но не могу сделать так, что бы картинка меняла свои css свойства в зависимости от размера. Изначально картинка правильно открывается, но что бы открыть ее после поворота, нужно либо ее переоткрыть либо перезагрузить страницу

Comment: Может вам стоит посмотреть в сторону JQuery mobile?

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема? Ориентация устройства сменилась, сделай новый ajax запрос и подгрузи картинку заново.

Comment: покажи код, как изменить картинку которая подгрузилась????

Comment: И зачем тут вообще ajax запрос